# How to get slot props with render functions in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to transform a Vue component I've made in a render function. Problem is I can't find a way to access the named slot props, like in the example:

```html
<template #slot-name="slotProps">
  <MyComponent v-bind="slotProps" />
</template>
```

There's a way to transform this code in a render function ?

Answer (score 2):

To pass a scoped slot, use the [`scopedSlots` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments) of the 2nd argument to `h()` (`createElement()`) in the form of `{ name: props => VNode | Array<VNode> }`.

For example, assuming your template is:

```html
<MySlotConsumer>
  <template #mySlot="slotProps">
    <MyComponent v-bind="slotProps" />
  </template>
</MySlotConsumer>
```

The equivalent render function would be:

```js
export default {
  render(h) {
    return h(MySlotConsumer, {
      scopedSlots: {
        mySlot: slotProps => h(MyComponent, { props: slotProps })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-scoped-slots-in-render-functions-in-vue-n7de8?file=/src/components/MyRender.js)